# wordpress invalid form submission

Tags: php, wordpress, file-upload

i have a form with a upload button, when i click the send button i want to upload the pdf file, but the var_dump(); print this error: "Invalid form submission."

php code:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'wp_handle_upload' ) ) {
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
}
if ( isset($_POST["submit"])) {

    $uploadedfile = $_FILES['fileToUpload'];
    $upload_overrides = wp_handle_upload($uploadedfile, array(
        'test_form' => false,
        'mimes' => get_allowed_mime_types()
    ));
    $movefile = wp_handle_upload( $uploadedfile, $upload_overrides );
    if ( $movefile ) {
    echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
    var_dump( $movefile);
    } else {
        echo "Possible file upload attack!\n";
    }
}
```

thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

Are you defining `$upload_overrides` somewhere?

If not, changing this

```
$movefile = wp_handle_upload( $uploadedfile, $upload_overrides );
```

To

```
$movefile = wp_handle_upload( $uploadedfile, array( 'test_form' => false ) );
```

should to the trick.

### EDIT

So, I think you'll have to use `media_handle_upload` instead of `wp_handle_upload`:

```
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php' );

$thumbnail_id = media_handle_upload('fileToUpload', $post_id);
```

More details in [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/media_handle_upload)

Comment: Invalid form submission.